# Image uploading in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

how to convert base64string into a image and store it in a location while uploading to the server in vue js.

Now I have base64string from the image but i should send the path of the image stored in that location in

Comment: You cant do it with Vue only.  What language or framework are you using in the backend?

Comment: Hello there, you need to tell us what lang/framework are you using for the backend.

In my case i used php with vue in my first attemp with vue, and i had problems with image upload as well. I think the headers are the problem. If you use axios you will not have problems with header when you send an image. And with php you need to receive it in the $_FILES variable.

Comment: I use java with spring4 framework as by backend . I need to send the path of stored image as a string to my backend service.